# how can i selected a button to select a size for a shopping cart app using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-class

this is my code in controller

```
$scope.status = false;
  $scope.clickOn = function () {

    if ($scope.status == false) {
      this.status = true;
    } else {
      this.status=false;
   }
  };
```

here is my html field

```
<div class="sizes">
                    <button ng-repeat="size in $ctrl.cart.sizes" class="button-size"
                        ng-class="{true:'active',false:'deactive'}[status]" ng-click="clickOn()">
                        <span>{{size}} UK</span>
                    </button>

                </div>
```

when I click on the button the class active have been used but when I click again the class deactive never work
there are any solution for this ?? thanks you guys so much

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add "track by $index" and activate/deactivate the button based on the $index. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).